# Monitors 3440x1440 34" vs 2560x1440 31,5"/32" for work and games

Tags: gaming, monitors

Advise, what is better for work (many open windows, 2 working windows on 1 screen at least - a browser on the left, a code editor on the right, for example, etc.) and at the same time for games. I can't choose between 2K / 31-32" and Ultrawide 3440x1440 34".

It seems that Ultrawide is good (for work, it certainly will be), but somehow I don't want to see black stripes on the sides (in games, during cutscenes). Can you conveniently place 2 or more program windows on a 2K monitor 31-32 inches?

Answer (score 0):

Some gamers prefer ultrawide, especially the ones that are racing (thats not me btw, I play minecraft). I would prefer the bigger screen for word though, because my programming IDE tends to take a lot of space for tests, git, log... So the ultrawide would be nice for me but I don't have one, because those are generally more expensive than other monitors. (and my current monitor setup is also ok)

You can get more windows on a 16/9 monitor, if you put one window on the outer side edge, Windows (10/11) will put that window on one half of the screen and ask you which window to put on the other half. (also works on ultrawide btw)